# How do I average one field while grouping by another in using RDDs with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am getting wrapped around the axle between `groupBy`, `aggregate`, `reduceByKey`, `map`, etc.  My goal is to average out field 16 (the last field) for each unique value of field 2.

So the output might look something like:

```
NW  -8
DL  -6
OO  -1
```

Given an RDD with the following elements:

> [u'2002-04-28,NW,19386,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1220,1252,32,1316,1350,34', u'2012-05-04,OO,20304,LSE,WI,43.87,-91.25,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1130,1126,-4,1220,1219,-1', u'2002-08-18,NW,19386,BDL,CT,41.93,-72.68,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,805,804,-1,959,952,-7', u'2004-07-29,NW,19386,BDL,CT,41.93,-72.68,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,800,757,-3,951,933,-18', u'2008-07-21,NW,19386,IND,IN,39.71,-86.29,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1143,1140,-3,1228,1222,-6', u'2007-10-29,NW,19386,RST,MN,43.9,-92.5,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1546,1533,-13,1639,1609,-30', u'2012-12-24,DL,19790,BOS,MA,42.36,-71,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1427,1431,4,1648,1635,-13', u'2010-04-22,DL,19790,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,930,927,-3,1028,1008,-20', u'2010-06-01,DL,19790,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,93.22,835,846,11,930,946,16', u'2003-09-04,NW,19386,BUF,NY,42.94,-78.73,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,900,852,-8,1017,955,-22']

Comment: This is airline data, so the 2nd field in each line is the airline code.  The last field in each line is arrival delay in minutes.  What I am trying to do is get the average delay time for each airline code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution :

```
data = [u'2002-04-28,NW,19386,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1220,1252,32,1316,1350,34', u'2012-05-04,OO,20304,LSE,WI,43.87,-91.25,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1130,1126,-4,1220,1219,-1', u'2002-08-18,NW,19386,BDL,CT,41.93,-72.68,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,805,804,-1,959,952,-7', u'2004-07-29,NW,19386,BDL,CT,41.93,-72.68,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,800,757,-3,951,933,-18', u'2008-07-21,NW,19386,IND,IN,39.71,-86.29,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1143,1140,-3,1228,1222,-6', u'2007-10-29,NW,19386,RST,MN,43.9,-92.5,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1546,1533,-13,1639,1609,-30', u'2012-12-24,DL,19790,BOS,MA,42.36,-71,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,1427,1431,4,1648,1635,-13', u'2010-04-22,DL,19790,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,930,927,-3,1028,1008,-20', u'2010-06-01,DL,19790,DTW,MI,42.21,-83.35,MSP,MN,44.88,93.22,835,846,11,930,946,16', u'2003-09-04,NW,19386,BUF,NY,42.94,-78.73,MSP,MN,44.88,-93.22,900,852,-8,1017,955,-22']
current_rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd = current_rdd.map(lambda x : (x.split(","))).map(lambda x : (x[1],x[-1])) \
                 .groupByKey() \ # group by key
                 .map(lambda x : (x[0], map(int, list(x[1])))) \ # convert resultiterable to list
                 .map(lambda x : (x[0], float(sum(x[1]))/len(x[1]))) # compute average on list for each key
# output
rdd.take(10)
# [(u'DL', -5.666666666666667), (u'NW', -8.166666666666666), (u'OO', -1.0)]
```

Comment: Thanks again.  Great stuff.  I owe you!!

Comment: The solution isn't optimized so far. But I don't like coding in python and this is straightforward to right an understand !

Comment: Exactly - straightforward comes before optimize.  I'm partial to Python

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is a shot in the dark as I don't have any environment to try this on (and it sucks)

I assume you have a RDD in data already splitted

```
mappedData  = data.map(lambda d : (d[1], d[-1])).cache      // (NW,34), (OO,-1), (NW,-7)
groupedData = mappedData.groupByKey().mapValues(len)        //  (NW, (34, -7)) ->  (NW, 2)
sumData = mappedData.groupByKey().mapValues(sum)            //  (NW, (34, -7)) ->  (NW, 27)
sumData.join(groupedData).map(lambda (x,y) => (x, y[0] / y[1]  )) (NW, (27,2)) -> (NW, 27/2)
```